# WooCommerce display Vendor name on Cart Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a request to change the "Sold By" name that appears in the cart checkout product area to the Vendor name. I would like to know if this is possible and if so how?

Here is a link to the site

http://dev.gtechteam.com/gg2

You will see in the Cart when you add an item that it that it says **Sold By**: Go Getter which is the business, but I would like it to say the vendors name so customers will know where the items are coming from and not be confused

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself? Usually you try it, and if you fail, post the code that is not working.

Comment: Kindly, this question is really too short and need more details… Where do you get the vendors name (meaning which code or where is located the data… Is it the product post author?). Can we have a screen shot or a live link?

Comment: I'm usually on the front-end side of things so my WP PHP knowledge is limited. Yes @Pharaoh I know how this works, not a newbie to the board, just not familiar with accessing this type of data in WP. Let me see if I can generate some code...if at all

Answer (score 0):

You must try this, hope this will solve your issue.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data','your_function_name',10,2 );

function your_function_name( $item_data, $cart_item ){

    $item_data[] = array('key'=>'sold by', 'value'=>'your vendor name');
    return $item_data;
}
```